# JQuery not detecting change in DIV id for animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am creating a navigation sidebar which slides open, and I am having trouble getting my JQuery to recognise that a div has had a change in id.

When inspecting the element, I can see that the id does actually change to closebutton, but when clicking it executes the openbutton.click script.

I've added some test counters to the console - any guidance is much appreciated!

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6vg3tzcz/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="nav">   
        <div id="openbutton">
        </div>    
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: -50%;

    margin-left: 50px;

    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: yellow;
}

#openbutton  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;

    height:50px;
    width:50px;

    background-color: black;
}

#closebutton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;

    height:50px;
    width:50px;

    background-color: blue;
}
```

**JS**

```
        $(document).ready (function() {
            $( "#openbutton" ).click(function() {
                console.log( "1" );
                $( "#nav" ).animate({left: "0", marginLeft: 0});
                console.log( "2" );
                $( "#nav" ).animate({left: "-10", marginLeft: 0} );
                console.log( "3" );
                $("#openbutton").attr("id", "closebutton");
            });

            $( "#closebutton" ).click(function() {
                console.log( "4" );
                $( "#nav" ).animate({left: "-50%", marginLeft: 40}, "slow" );
                console.log( "5" );
                $( "#nav" ).animate({left: "-50%", marginLeft: 50}, "slow" );
                console.log( "6" );
                $("#closebutton").attr("id", "openbutton"); 
            }); 
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `on` event to attach events on live dom elements - like below -

```
 $(document).ready (function() {

        $( "#nav" ).on('click','#openbutton',function() {
            console.log( "1" );
            $( "#nav" ).animate({left: "0", marginLeft: 0});
            console.log( "2" );
            $( "#nav" ).animate({left: "-10", marginLeft: 0} );
            console.log( "3" );
            $("#openbutton").attr("id", "closebutton");
        });

        $( "#nav" ).on('click','#closebutton',function() {
            console.log( "4" );
            $( "#nav" ).animate({left: "-50%", marginLeft: 40}, "slow" );
            console.log( "5" );
            $( "#nav" ).animate({left: "-50%", marginLeft: 50}, "slow" );
            console.log( "6" );
            $("#closebutton").attr("id", "openbutton");

        });

    });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6vg3tzcz/4/

Comment: Hi Dayvson, thanks for replying. I've added the on("click") function as you've recommended, but I am having the same problem. Might I be missing something else?

Comment: updated answer with working code and working jsfiddle link, try if it works

Answer (score 1):

Although I think the best approach would be use a class.
The problem is the binding time, you have to use the `.on()` in order to work

```
   $(document).on("click","#openbutton" function() {});  
   $(document).on("click","#closebutton" function() {});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple reason this isn't working. When you call your javascript when the page loads, there is no `closebutton` id, so this jQuery is basically meaningless.

You can set it up so that this part of your script is called only when the `openbutton` is clicked like so:

```
$(document).ready (function() {

            $( "#openbutton" ).click(function() {
                console.log( "1" );
                $( "#nav" ).animate({left: "0", marginLeft: 0});
                console.log( "2" );
                $( "#nav" ).animate({left: "-10", marginLeft: 0} );
                console.log( "3" );
                $("#openbutton").attr("id", "closebutton");
                closeit();
            });
            function closeit(){
            $( "#closebutton" ).click(function() {
                console.log( "4" );
                $( "#nav" ).animate({left: "-50%", marginLeft: 40}, "slow" );
                console.log( "5" );
                $( "#nav" ).animate({left: "-50%", marginLeft: 50}, "slow" );
                console.log( "6" );
                $("#closebutton").attr("id", "openbutton");

            });
            }
        });
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6vg3tzcz/3/